# Что такое academic programming track?

Tags: справка

[image: Меню выбора направлений на codewars]

Решила зарегистрироваться на codewars, но столкнулась с таким направлением разработки, как academic. Пожалуйста, можете объяснить что это, для чего оно используется и какие задачи оно решает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это опция для тех, кто совсем новый в IT и хочет решать больше учебных заданий